# Unity: Issues using an external library (SharpConfig)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll

I am attempting to use the SharpConfig library in the code of my 2D Unity project. I downloaded the .zip and extracted the .dll file, which I then placed into the Assets folder of my project. In one of my scripts, I called functions from that file, and it compiled successfully. When I ran the game, I got the error

```
"Unloading broken assembly Assets/Scripts/SharpConfig.dll, this assembly can cause crashes in the runtime."
```

After pushing the button, I get the error:

```
TypeLoadException: Could not find method due to a type load error
MenuController.LoadQuickplaySetup () (at Assets/Scripts/MenuController.cs:140)
MenuController.OnClick () (at Assets/Scripts/MenuController.cs:184)
MenuController.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/MenuController.cs:33)
```

Where LoadQuickplaySetup() is called from the OnClick() method I wrote (which works on every button), which contains functions found in the SharpConfig library, and MenuController is the script that I wrote.

This issue was not resolved by restarting Unity and trying again.

How would I go about fixing this issue? Did I miss any steps in the process of importing the library?

Unity version is 2018.3.0f2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually resolved the issue. The SharpConfig download contains two folders inside the SharpConfig/bin directory, DotNetCore and DotNetStandard, each with their own SharpConfig.dll file. I initially used the file from DotNetCore, but after updating my version of Unity from 2018.3.0 to 2018.3.4, I replaced the file with the one from the DotNetStandard directory, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

When this error happens, it means the dll you imported has dependencies and you didnt add them to your project, to know what dll you are missing can try to create a console app and put

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(TheDLLpath);
```

In the `Main`method and then read the exception that should happen to know what dependency you are missing.

(You may also need a `using System.Reflection;` in your console app.)

Comment: Was not necessary, but I appreciate your help.